# Copy dynamic pictures in Excel to PowerPoint

Tags: excel, powerpoint

I have an excel spreadsheet in which I dynamically insert pictures of smileys based on numbers in column A (if positive a happy smiley appears, if negative a sad smiley appears).

```
       A               B                C
1     5%          happy smiley
2     8%          happy smiley
3     -4%         sad smiley
4     -3%         sad smiley
```

This function works perfectly within Excel.
Now, I want to transfer the pictures of the smileys 
into a PowerPoint presentation with the Paste Link function.
The same way I can insert charts from Excel to PowerPoint.
However, it seems that I can not use this option for the picture.

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue and to copy
the dynamic smileys from Excel to PowerPoint?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you just want to copy the smileys to show them in your presentation?

If you do so, you can, in powerpoint, while pasting them, select "as graphic" or something like this. I'm not at a computer right now to test it out, but this should work.

**Edit**
Source for this answer: [this link here](http://www.thinkoutsidetheslide.com/automatic-updating-of-excel-tables-in-powerpoint-slides/)

Copy the corresponding cells in excel. In powerpoint, go to "home", then there on the paste button to the submenu and select "special paste" or so. Then you can select "shortcut" or "link" or whatever [like in this image](http://www.thinkoutsidetheslide.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/image002.jpg). It should now update when you update the cells in excel.

Comment: Yeah I can copy and paste them as graphic into PowerPoint but the smileys in the excel will change based on the values in column A. For example it can happen that the percentage in cell A1 switches to -10% and then also the smiley will change from a happy to a sad one. I want this change also to happen in the PowerPoint so I do not have to copy the smileys all the time something changes in the Excel.